# how to change a specific list item text right to left (eg. arabic/hebrew)?

Tags: html, css

I have a list item with hebrew text I'd like to change text direction to right to left. But unfortunately it doesn't effect anything.

Why is dir="rtl" not working properly? And how can I achieve to change text direction?

My concrete example:

```html
<ul>
  Le colophon se situe sur la page de titre au folio <a href="#">1r</a>:
  <li>
    <span class="underline">Transcription :</span><br><br>
    <span class="right-to-left" dir="rtl">
      וצורת בית המקדש תוב''ב אכי''ר<br><br>
      כצמח השדה יגדל וירבה<br><br>
      למעלה למעלה הקטן גרשון<br><br>
      בן ה''ה האלוף והקצין הטפסר<br><br>
      פרנס ומנהיג התורני הרר<br><br>
      צבי הירש ברעסלא סגל<br><br>
      מק''ק המבורג- על ידי הכותב<br><br>
      והסופר משולם המכונה זימל ב''הרר<br><br>
      משה מק''ק פאלין בעיר ווין ובאותיות<br><br>
      אמשטרדם<br><br>
      בשנת אומץ גבורתך<br><br>
      ה'פ'ל'א'ת' בפסח לפ''ק
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    foo
  </li>
  <li>
    bar
  </li>
</ul>
```

PS: I don't want to use `float:right` on span.right-to-left

Comment: make your span a block .... (give it a border to see where it stands, then reset display)

Comment: @GCyrillus, can you provide this as an answer? It works!

Comment: i made an answer and added a link to a tut about unicode-bidi https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/u/unicode-bidi/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `span`  into a `block` (anything should do, but not inline ! ).

You may also want to take a look at: [`unicode-bidi`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/u/unicode-bidi/)

```css
.right-to-left {
display:block;
direction:rtl;
unicode-bidi:bidi-override
}
```

```html
    <ul>
      Le colophon se situe sur la page de titre au folio <a href="#">1r</a>:
      <li>
        <span class="underline">Transcription :</span><br><br>
        <span class="right-to-left" dir="rtl">
        is that working ?<br/>
          וצורת בית המקדש תוב''ב אכי''ר<br><br>
          כצמח השדה יגדל וירבה<br><br>
          למעלה למעלה הקטן גרשון<br><br>
          בן ה''ה האלוף והקצין הטפסר<br><br>
          פרנס ומנהיג התורני הרר<br><br>
          צבי הירש ברעסלא סגל<br><br>
          מק''ק המבורג- על ידי הכותב<br><br>
          והסופר משולם המכונה זימל ב''הרר<br><br>
          משה מק''ק פאלין בעיר ווין ובאותיות<br><br>
          אמשטרדם<br><br>
          בשנת אומץ גבורתך<br><br>
          ה'פ'ל'א'ת' בפסח לפ''ק
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        foo
      </li>
      <li>
        bar
      </li>
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using `text-align:right;` in you css for `.right-left`?